# Getting all the column name and turning them into variables and then back again

Tags: php, mysql

If I have a table with column names name, address, state (for example), how can I make each one into a variable name - for example I dont' wish to do it the long hard way of

```
$name=$table['name'];
etc etc
```

and then I wish to upgrade them all quickly without going the long way of

```
UPDATE name='$name', address='$address' etc etc
```

Comment: "the long way" is the right way

Comment: Assuming from your syntax example you are using PHP, so I added the tag.

Comment: if you don't want "the long way", what's the point in having all the separate variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP, the extract() function creates variables according to the keys in the associative array argument you give it.

```
$table['name'] = 'bob';
extract($table);
print $name; // prints bob
```

See http://php.net/extract

---

If you want to generate an UPDATE statement dynamically from a hash array, I'd do it with query parameters this way:

```
$table = array('name' = 'bob' ...etc);
$sql = "UPDATE mytable SET " 
  . join(",", array_map(function($field) { return "$field=:$field"; }, $table)) 
  . " WHERE ...";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($table);
```

Comment: Good point, I didn't know about that function - and also `compact()` for the opposite way. Then he can do simple `foreach` on the array to construct the UPDATE query.